# give reporting services data from webpage

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a report server (2005). I want my webpage to create dataset/datasource and use it on a report hosted on my report server.

for a local report, I would use

```
   ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource { Name = "DataSet1", Value = cs };//cs is a list of maybe customer.

   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
```

we assume/suppose that my report server cannot get the data by himself.

Comment: What is the result from the above call? Have you seen this article -->https://arcanecode.com/2009/02/09/using-a-local-reporting-services-2008-report-with-an-adonet-data-set/

Comment: have a look on this link https://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2015/06/ssrs-report-in-aspnet-example.html

Comment: my report is on a server, the rdl directly. its like this, but I want to give all data. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsexecutionservice2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx

Comment: your links use localReport like my example, but I dont want to use a local report.